# Asp.net Checkbox issues after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, postback

This is an asp.net project with C#

I have a `GridView` that has a checkbox column. The user selects a row by clicking the appropriate checkbox. They then can act on this row by doing various things (mostly button clicks). The problem that I am having is that when a user clicks a button, the gridview is refreshed. Most of the time this consists of a row being deleted. When a user goes to select another checkbox (another row in the gridview) to act upon, you can briefly see it check the box and then the checkbox is immediately unchecked OR the checkbox below the one they are wanting to select gets checked. When this is occurring, the `onCheckedChanged` does not fire. BUT when I refresh the page, selecting and deselecting checkboxes works just as intended without any issues whatsoever.

Just as a few sidenotes:

1. I am doing row highlighting using Javascript based upon what checkbox is selected. (I can provide this code if needed)
2. I am ensuring that only one checkbox is selected at a time using the code below under the checkchanged event:

   ```
   CheckBox activeCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;

   foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView1.Rows)
   {
       CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)rw.FindControl("RowLevelCheckBox1");
       if (chkBx != activeCheckBox)
       {
           chkBx.Checked = false;
       }
       else if (chkBx == activeCheckBox && (chkBx.Checked != false && activeCheckBox.Checked != false))
       {
           chkBx.Checked = true;
       }
   }
   ```
3. I am binding the gridview in the codebehind in the page load within an if (!IsPostBack)
4. Before you ask, yes I have set `autopostback="true"` on the checkbox

When the button is clicked I am setting the `checkbox.checked = false`, but when I debug and check all the checkboxes in the gridview on the page load, after all code has been executed, it still shows that one is checked.

Why is this behavior happening?

Comment: is the code you posted being hit before the postback or after the postback..? did you put breakpoints in the `Page_Load` section as well as the section where you have posted the code..?

Comment: I agree with MethodMan, you need to verify the order of page events being fired (Init, Load, Render) and maybe try disabling the viewstate on checkbox control.

Comment: @MethodMan That code is in the CheckedChangedEvent it only gets hit when the checkbox is checked or unchecked...supposedly. It doesn't get hit in the situation I mentioned. I've literally placed breakpoints everywhere and can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: @MethodMan AHHH I see what you were asking. That code is being hit after the postback it seems. If I set a breakpoint on the page load and on that event. The page load happens BEFORE it hits the event. Is this intended?

Comment: It seems as if the viewstate of the deleted row checkbox (which at the time would've been checked) is being carried to the row above it (if there was not any rows beneath the deleted row) or it is being carried to the row below (if there was a row beneath the deleted row). How can i blow that checkboxe's viewstate away completely so that it doesn't move to any other checkboxes within the `GridView`? Setting the `.Checked` field before rebinding the `GridView` doesn't seem to do anything. Anyone out there have any idea?

Comment: You have to understand Postbacks and webPage Life Cycle.. there are a few ways around this.. you could set the causes Auto postback of the dropdowns to false and inside of the button click you can check for the value of the first dropdown.. then execute a query etc.. or you could wrap the controls inside of an UpdatePanel as well this will cause partial postback.. and you would want to do some javascript calling method on the OnClient events that are available to you..